# Datanucleus schema generation ignores "inheritance strategy=" directive

Tags: orm, schema, datanucleus

I'm working with the Datanucleus tutorial application for JDO, [specifically this one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/datanucleus/files/datanucleus-samples/2.1/datanucleus-samples-jdo-tutorial-2.1-src.zip/download).

Regardless which "inheritance strategy" I try the table layout is the same. I would like two tables, one for PRODUCT and one for BOOK, but using the configuration below I only get the PRODUCT table with columns for both class Product and class Book.

```
   <class name="Product" identity-type="sequence">
        <inheritance strategy="complete-table"/>
        <field name="name">
            <column name="PRODUCT_NAME" length="100" jdbc-type="VARCHAR"/>
        </field>
        <field name="description">
            <column length="255" jdbc-type="VARCHAR"/>
        </field>
    </class>

    <class name="Book" identity-type="sequence">
        <field name="author">
            <column length="40" jdbc-type="VARCHAR"/>
        </field>
        <field name="isbn">
            <column length="20" jdbc-type="CHAR"/>
        </field>
        <field name="publisher">
            <column length="40" jdbc-type="VARCHAR"/>
        </field>
    </class>
```

The directory structure is exactly as in the tutorial, as is the build.xml. I have tried generating the schema via both the Ant task and the command line.

I use the sequence of commands:

```
    ant clean
    ant compile
    ant enhance
    ant createschema
```

The schema is generated but not as the Datanucleus documentation suggests that it should be with inheritance strategy "compete-table."

My target database is PostgreSQL 8.4 running on Ubuntu 10.04 if that matters.

Anyone else run into this issue and found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:

In the datanucleus tutorial download, the build.xml file given has a "createschema" target like:

```
<target name="createschema">
    ...

    <schematool ...>
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/target/classes">
            <include name="**/*.class"/>
        </fileset>
        ...
    </schematool>
</target>
```

It should be changed to include all .jdo files as shown below:

```
<target name="createschema">
    ...

    <schematool ...>
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/target/classes">
            <include name="**/*.class"/>
            <include name="**/*.jdo"/>
        </fileset>
        ...
    </schematool>
</target>
```

In addition the package-hsql.orm file needs to be renamed to package-hsql.jdo and its header needs to be changed to:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE jdo PUBLIC
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Java Data Objects ORM Metadata 2.0//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/orm_2_0.dtd">
<jdo>
    ...
<jdo>
```

Notice that the DOCTYPE and root element were changed. The root element was "orm" and changed to "jdo".

Once I made these changes the schema generation tool followed the "inheritance strategy" directive.

Comment: Nothing needs to be changed. I run the current version (2.2) using Ant and it all works. Your situation is symptomatic of someone who didn't use the provided build.xml and consequently don't have the ORM files in your CLASSPATH

Comment: Alright, I will try the 2.2 version. The issues above were from trying the 2.1 version.

Answer (score 0):

For my custom application, I had a similar issue, and it worked fine after making the changes in the header of the jdo file. I am using version 3.2.9.